# Single Word for an Unfortunate Coincidence?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that is able to be used instead of the phrase "unfortunate coincidence"?

Comment: There is, but by unfortunate coincidence, it is at this exact moment convalescing from a broken L at a Swiss sanitarium and is not able to be used, nor will be for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Yes its a calamity

Comment: Did you look for synonyms of 'coincidence' that might have the flavor of unfortunate?

Comment: I wonder if "misadventure" isn't the word you're looking for.  "Mischance" is another possibility.

Answer (score 7):

There is no single word (noun) that refers to coincidence, *unlucky* is an adjective, therefore the nearest thing I can suggest is:

[**mishap**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mishap)

noun mis·hap \ˈmis-ˌhap, mis-ˈ\

: a small mistake or amount of bad luck

: an unlucky accident or mistake

- "*We experienced the usual mishaps of a family vacation*".

cross-posted

Comment: @Mac could you reference your link/quote.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider [mishap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mishap)

> An unlucky accident

or [misfortune](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misfortune)

> An unfortunate condition or event

<sub>From Oxford</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I nominate ***unlucky.***

> It was an unfortunate coincidence that his nemesis was on the same train.
>   It was unlucky that...

It's not quite in the same league as using two four-syllable words, though. It also fails to impart the potential ironic understatement of "unfortunate coincidence": that it was actually an absolute disaster. Nuanced meanings are rare when restricted to single words, although *unlucky* might possibly fit if an understatement is needed. Usually, using a more complicated phrase begs the question as to why it was chosen and what additional meaning is implied.

Consequently, although *unlucky* fits the question's stated criteria [as at the time of this answer, anyway], there may not actually be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Unserendipitous* comes to mind. Perhaps *nonserendipitous* but I would rank *unserendipity* as less serendipitous than *nonserendipity*.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU.  Just so you are aware, I would recommend changing your username to something less generally offensive before it gets flagged and [changed for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156926/281446).

Answer (score 0):

How about an "ill-fortune"?

Other possibilities: mischance and contretemps.